# Installing unixODBC on CentOS 7 fails: libodbcinst.so.1 => not found

Tags: oracle, centos, unixodbc

I'm trying to install unixODBC on CentOS7 by following the steps found here:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Oracle-from-RHEL-or-Centos

I've completed everything up to the step where it asks to test the oracle driver isntallation. When I run `dltest /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1`, I get the following error:

```
# dltest /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libsqora.so.11.1
[dltest] ERROR dlopen: file not found
```

I then run ldd on the `libsqora.so.11.1` file:

```
# ldd libsqora.so.11.1
ldd: warning: you do not have execution permission for `./libsqora.so.11.1'
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd57f6f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f55a0534000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f55a0232000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f55a0016000)
        libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f559fdfc000)
        libclntsh.so.11.1 => /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 
(0x00007f559d48d000)
        libodbcinst.so.1 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f559d0c0000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f55a0738000)
        libnnz11.so => /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libnnz11.so 
(0x00007f559ccf3000)
        libaio.so.1 => /lib64/libaio.so.1 (0x00007f559caf1000)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?